# WCF: How to use AllowInsecureTransport

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Within the context of .NET 4 WCF, I am attempting to use the new AllowInsecureTransport attribute so that I can use my custom authentication without using SSL (in our development environment only - we are using SSL in production).

My bindings config looks like:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CustomAuthentication">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" allowInsecureTransport="true">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

However, I am getting a *Unrecognized attribute 'allowInsecureTransport'* error.
This attribute was described in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/89145532-5fdb-4e32-984e-f0efb4a21551), and has [help on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.securitybindingelement.allowinsecuretransport.aspx).

**Can someone help me with my rather inept knowledge of WCF config options and point me in the right direction?**

I'd prefer not to use the [ClearUsernameBinding](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html) as described [here](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html), but will if there is no other inbuilt option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do believe that element is only usable through a custom binding... if you see the docs, it's part of the SecurityBindingElement, not part of a standard binding like wsHttpBinding. The thread you pointed to does have an example of a configuration using a custom binding to enable it.